# Cannot control looping when converting video to gif in FFMPEG

Tags: ffmpeg, gif

I am trying to create a gif that loops twice from a movie, but whatever I try it loops continuously:

```
ffmpeg -i animation.mov -loop 2 animation.gif
```

Using ffmpeg version 4.1.3 on Mac

Comment: Works for me except that `-loop 1` is used to loop twice. What are you using to view the GIF?

Comment: Thanks, I was previewing it using _Quicklook_ on OSX (Spacebar shortcut). I have now discovered loops infinitely regardless of how many are set!

Comment: Feel free to add an answer since you found the actual problem.

Answer (score 1):

Solved by not previewing using Quicklook (spacebar) in OS X